# $3x+3y-1,4x^2+y-5,4x+2y$ are sides of an equilateral triangle

Tags: euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry, triangles

I am completely lost in this one

$3x+3y-1,4x^2+y-5,4x+2y$ are sides of  an equilateral triangle, its area is closest to the which integer?

Comment: Is there anything you *can* do with this information, even if you don't know whether or not it will lead to an answer?

Comment: As has been pointed out in one of the answers, this question makes no sense as one of the lines is a curve, not a straight line. I guess the question was meant to say that the points of intersection of these curves gave the three points of the triangle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From equating first and third equations, you get $y=x+1$. Use this in another two of the equations to get values of $x$ and $y$. Then use the formula for the area of a triangle.